# Squaring a vector using geometric algebra

Tags: geometric-algebras

I'm doing research involving clifford algebra and I'm having difficulty understanding this one axiom: $a^2  = g(a,a)$. It states that this is the square of a vector and dividing the original vector by this can give an inverse vector. I was wondering how I should go about calculating this.

Comment: Do you understand that $g$ is some metric--some function of two vectors that gives the "dot" or "inner" product between them?

Answer (score 3):

If $a^2  = g(a,a)\neq 0$, then, $\frac{1}{g(a,a)}a$ is clearly the inverse of $a$.

As for "understanding" the axiom, it is simply one of the defining features of a Clifford algebra. The quadratic form associated with the bilinear form is encoded into the product by design. We do this because we can do useful things with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what it is you don't understand.

Given a vector space $V$ with a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form, $B$, you define its Clifford algebra as:
$$
\operatorname{Cl}(V,B) = \bigotimes V\,/\, I\left(u\otimes v+v\otimes u-2B(u,v)1_{\otimes V}\,\left.\right\rvert u,v\in V\,\right).
$$
Where $\otimes V$ is the tensor algebra of $V$ and $I(\cdots)$ is the ideal generated by these elementes. This implies that in the Clifford algebra (in the quotient),
$$
uv + vu = 2B(u,v)1_{\operatorname{Cl}}.
$$
There isn't anything to calculate here, this is only a "symbolic" construction. If, for example, you were working with some *representation* of the Clifford algebra (like the [gamma matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) in the Dirac equation), the product is represented  as the matrix product.